# I'm struggling to append an id from mysql to the URL

Tags: http, go, redirect

I'm trying to append an id (and other info) to the url, so I can access it later, but I can't find the right method after some research.

I've tried to use Get() method, query(), Add(), but I couldn't redirect the URL.

```
var email_ployer string

func RegisterNewPloyer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/ployer/register" {
        http.Error(w, "404 not found.", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    db := connect.ConnectDB()
    defer db.Close()
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        email_ployer = r.FormValue("email")
        senha := r.FormValue("senha")
        senha, _ = HashPassword(senha)
        tx, _ := db.Begin()
        stmt, _ := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO ployers(email_ployer, senha_ployer) VALUES(?,?)")
        _, erro := stmt.Exec(email_ployer, senha)
        if erro != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            log.Fatal(erro)
        }
        tx.Commit()
    }
    Redirect(w, r)
}

func Redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db2 := connect.ConnectDB()
    defer db2.Close()
    var id string
    tx, _ := db2.Begin()
    rows, _ := tx.Query("SELECT id FROM ployers WHERE email_ployer = '?'", email_ployer)
    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&id); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    http.Redirect(w, r, x, http.StatusSeeOther)
}




func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/ployer/seja-um-de-nos", LoadPloyerContent)
    http.HandleFunc("/ployer/register", register.RegisterNewPloyer)
    http.HandleFunc("/ployer/complete/", LoadPloyerContent)
    http.HandleFunc("/ployer/register-received", LoadPloyerContent)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3306", nil))
}
```

In my system, I want the user to register his E-mail and password, create an new user in the DB and redirect the URL to something like localhost:3306/ployer/complete/id

Comment: Note you're silencing a lot of errors in this code (e.g. `rows, _ := tx.Query(..)`, which is almost certainly not a good idea. What if you have a typo in the SQL query or parameter? Or what if something unexpected happens (database went away)? You should always check errors! Also, `email_ployer = '?'` looks incorrect? You don't need the quotes there, as you're using parametrized queries. Not sure if his is related to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `res.LastInsertId()` to get the id and pass it to your redirect function, and build the url:

```
func RegisterNewPloyer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  //...
  //...
  res, erro := stmt.Exec(email_ployer, senha)
  if erro != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    log.Fatal(erro)
  }
  tx.Commit()
  id, erro := res.LastInsertId()
  if erro != nil {
    log.Fatal(erro)
  }
  Redirect(w, r, id)
}

func Redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, id int64) {
    uri := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:3306/ployer/complete/%d", id)
    http.Redirect(w, r, uri, http.StatusSeeOther)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `url.Values` to construct a map of query string values. Later on, you can use `Encode` method to generate encoded query string. Assign this value to `Url.RawQuery` to get the final output.

e.g.:

```
base, _ := url.Parse("https://www.foo.com/")

// Create an instance of Values to hold your query string parameters
values := url.Values{}
values.Add("abc", "def")

// Set the encoded output to RawQuery attribute of Url
base.RawQuery = values.Encode()

println(base.String())
```

If you are starting with a URL that already has query string parameters and you want add/modify items in it, use `Query()` method to obtain a reference to parsed map.

e.g.:

```
base, _ := url.Parse("https://www.foo.com/?a=b")

values := base.Query()
values.Set("a", "c")
values.Set("x", "y")

// Set the encoded output to RawQuery attribute of Url
base.RawQuery = values.Encode()

println(base.String())
```